# How to remove service from autostart?

Tags: systemctl, chkconfig

By default, if my Linux is booted, some services 
like `httpd, named` start automatically. 
I want to start them manually, I want to remove them from autostartup. 
In the internet, it is said that it is possible with `systemctl` and `chkconfig` commands. 
My Linux supports both of them. 
How exactly and which command I can do it with? 
My Linux version is: Redhat EL5.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If your system has both:

```
chkconfig service off

systemctl disable service
```

RHEL5 uses `chkconfig` by default. On a side note, I recommend upgrading because RHEL 5 has been EOL since March 31st, 2017 unless you have purchased the Extended Life Cycle Support Add-On subscription.

Comment: If I write on the terminal: `chkconfig httpd off` --> will it remove `httpd` from autostart?

Comment: What do you recommend upgrading? O/S? Is RHEL 5 only has been EOL? Or all releases of RHEL ?

Comment: @itdev 1) Yes, that command will stop the service from starting at boot. It would then need to be started manually which is what you want. 2) RHEL 5 is EOL. RHEL 6 and RHEL 7 are still supported. I recommend going to RHEL 7 as 6 is EOL next year.

Comment: Thank you for perfect explanation! And last question, how is it advised going to RHEL 7? By installing new OS or just by upgrading OS with some commands?

Comment: @itdev You must perform a fresh install.